# Вопрос по руби - как правильно оптимизировать вызовы из <%= partial '.../...' %>

Tags: ruby

Можно ли, используя вот эту строку:

```
<%= partial 'some/catalog/file' %>
```

вызывать разные куски из одного фала .erb?

Делаю статику HTML5. Необходимо сделать отдельные файлы на каждой странице (их множество), мета тэги, хотелось бы это все вызывать из одного файла .erb.

Работаю на фрэймворке middleman3. Kак это можно реализовать? Oчень много файлов, поэтому начинаешь путаться - что где находится.

Чтобы не путаться с формулировками и понятиями, выкладываю скрин о моём вопросе.

Возможно-ли такое?

[image: пример чего хотелось бы добиться...]

Comment: Не совсем поняла задачу, может быть вы ищете хелпер `content_for`?

Comment: а что делает этот хелпер - content_for ? Задача была такая, есть один файл *.erb и в нем разные куски html для разных страниц, так вот как объяснить где какой кусок кода взять? есть однотипные куски html для разных страниц и удобней их в одном месте править чем создавать кучу отдельных файлов, ведь так?)

Comment: если такое делать, то должно выглядеть что то вроде, в самом *.erb делаешь какие-то обозначения\выделения (не знаю как точно называться...) кусков html, а после уже при вызове их строкой <%= partial 'some/catalog/file' %> уже уточнения аля <%= partial 'some/catalog/file','уточнение'  %> это просто фантазия) может так и не работает совсем)

Comment: Может быть, вам стоит добавить конкретный код к вопросу? Пока выглядит так, что вы пытаетесь пойти неверным путём. Если ваш файл содержит очень разные части html и их надо рендерить в разных местах других вьюх, то гораздо удобнее будет разбить его на несколько отдельных партиалов и спокойно рендерить их в нужных местах

Comment: Посмотрите, добавил скриншот о вопросе с примером кода, возможно-ли такое сделать?

Comment: Теперь ваш вопрос стал ещё непонятнее. В вашем примере все 5 пар метатегов идентичны. Так оно и есть, или они всё-таки будут разные, но вы поленились отобразить это в примере? В любом случае, вставить вам их нужно только в лэйауты, если опять же пример верно отображает задачу. Если они разные - пишите напрямую в лайаут, нет смысла ничего выносить. Если одинаковые - один партиал на две строки, рендерите его в каждом лэйауте

Comment: да это то все понятно, что если один и тот же кусок кода то проблем нет, суть в том что он разный, это я просто для примера, что бы понятней было. Можно ли такие разные части в разные страницы выгружать, из одного файла или это невозможно. Одинаковые потому что не поленился, а потому что пока контента нет...

Comment: "работаю на фрэйме мидл3" - это что? [middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/)? [ask]

Comment: @Vision10, не сочтите за грубость, но если вы выкладываете пример, то позаботьтесь о том, чтобы он соотносился с реальностью, будет гораздо проще получить ответ.

Comment: да конечно, извините за то что непонятно написал) мидл3 - это middleman3

Answer (score 2):

в папке вашего проекта (**layouts**), добавьте файлы ( например **_header.html.erb**)
знак

> _

общепринят для указания того что это ***часть*** основного представления

а на основной странице ( **application.html.erb**) , куда будут собираться части ваших вьюх

выведите через рендер

```
<%=render 'layouts/header' %>
```

Также для скорости и сжатия html можете использовать [эту волшебную штуку](http://slim-lang.com/)

```
gem slim-rails
```

тогда весь код можно заменить на

```
= render 'layouts/header'
```

Comment: спасибо конечно... но не как это особо не помогло, суть то вопроса как из одно файла *.erb брать разные куски html для разын страниц. Но за gem slim-rails спасибо конечно)

Comment: Посмотрите, добавил скриншот о вопросе с примером кода, возможно-ли такое сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Должно работать через content_for, о котором я писала в самом начале. В ваш партиал собираете все нужные куски кода

```
# _my_very_big_mixing_up_all_the_stuff_partial.erb
<% content_for :contacts do %>
  <p>Contacts</p>
<% end %>

<% content_for :banner do %>
  <p>Banner</p>
<% end %>
```

Затем в лэйаутах первой строкой рендерите партиал и вызываете часть с нужным идентификатором

```
# layouts/contacts.erb
<%= partial 'partials/my_very_big_mixing_up_all_the_stuff_partial' %>
<%= yield_content :contacts %>

# layouts/banner.erb
<%= partial 'partials/my_very_big_mixing_up_all_the_stuff_partial' %>
<%= yield_content :banner %>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, выглядит то что нужно, только не очень понимаю что такое вьюхи... таким не пользовался... где этот файл рендерить ?

Comment: попробовал в самой странице отрендерить первой строкой (contact.html.erb) ошибка...

Comment: @Vision10, я только сейчас поняла, что речь не про рельсы... Зачем же вы тэг ruby-on-rails поставили? С миддлманом никогда не работала, но дока говорит, что там тоже есть content_for, только он вызывается по-другому. Ответ поправила, смотрите. И да, если у вас появляется ошибка, то неплохо бы её текст тоже выставлять на всеобщее обозрение

Comment: казалось что руби рельсы тоже что и руби) совсем начинающий... сделал как вы написали, ошибка та-же, вот скрин вывода 1- https://imgur.com/L7NgYgO 2- https://imgur.com/q823P98 3- https://imgur.com/NB2OtQW

Comment: @Vision10, руби - это язык, рельсы - фреймворк на рубях, миддлман - тоже фреймворк на рубях. Я еще раз поправила ответ, для партиалов надо использовать `partial` вместо `render`.  Не уверена, что смогу вам помочь с дальнейшим дебаггингом - о существовании миддлмана я узнала сегодня из вашего вопроса, так что постарайтесь довести идею с content_for до ума с помощью документации :)

Comment: Спасибо и на этом) буду думать... момент только в том что при таком вызове как "<%= partial 'partials/my_very_big_mixing_up_all_the_stuff_partial' %>" то всё что там есть и будет вызвано...

Comment: @Vision10, тогда хоть плюсик ответу поставьте, если хоть чем-то помогло :)

Comment: @ Василиса     Плюсик поставил, морально помогло)